# C++ Bubble Sort bug

Tags: c++

I am having issue with my code, the code is suppose to sort a set amount a number in ascending order, but every time I enter the 2nd last number the program ends, and in the place of what should be the 10th number is  `-858993460`

here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x, y, arry[61], z, interim;
    cout << "Please enter how many numbers you would like to sort:\n>> ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Please enter " << x << "numbers\n";
    for (y = 0; y < (x - 1); y++)
        cin >> arry[y];
    cout << "Give bubble sort a minute to do its thing.....";
    for (y = 0; y < (x - 1); y++)
    {
        for (z = 0; z < (x - y - 1); z++)
        {
            if (arry[z] > arry[z + 1])
            {
                interim = arry[z];
                arry[z] = arry[z + 1];
                arry[z + 1] = interim;
                

            }
        }
    }

    cout << "\nBubble sorted as went through the array in accending order\n Arry:";
    for (y = 0; y < x; y++)
        cout << arry[y] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to change the value of the array but not really tried anything else, and I'm expecting it to be able to let me input that last number but it never does.

Comment: You don’t read `arry[x-1]`, but print it.

Comment: `cin >> x;` you enter `2` here, for `x`, indicating that you wish to enter two numbers. Can you work out, on paper and pencil, how many times the next `for` loop runs, in order to enter the specified number of values? Spoiler alert: it won't run two times.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you made a tiny error in the `for...` loops. When you ask the user to input `x` numbers, your `for...` loop cuts the users reply short. The next `for...` loop following that one, where you tell the user to wait a minute for Bubble Sort, is also cut short.

Instead of:

```cpp
cout << "Please enter " << x << "numbers\n";
for (y = 0; y < (x - 1); y++)
   cin >> arry[y];
```

Your `for...` loop should look like this:

```cpp
cout << "Please enter " << x << "numbers\n";
for (y = 0; y < x; y++)
   cin >> arry[y];
```

This will allow for *exactly* `x` numbers to be saved from the user input.

and in the following `for...` loop, instead of:

```cpp
cout << "Give bubble sort a minute to do its thing.....";
for (y = 0; y < (x - 1); y++)
{
   //... your code here
}
```

It should be:

```cpp
cout << "Give bubble sort a minute to do its thing.....";
for (y = 0; y < x; y++)
{
   //... your code here
}
```

After making these adjustments, I tested out your code and it works as intended.

> every time I enter the 2nd last number the program ends

This happened because the first `for...` loop cut your user input short by 1 value, where your looping condition was `y < (x-1)`. If you set `x` to be a small number like `5` and you count from `y = 0` up to `(x-1)` (or `5-1` in this case), like in your original `for...` loop, you'll notice that your `for...` loop only loops 4 times, and only records 4 values from the user input, not `5` values.
For future reference, remember that arrays are 0-indexed, meaning that they start with the index 0. So if you want to loop over 5 elements of an array, you would loop through the indices `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. This is the same as:
`for(y = 0, y < 5; y++)`
The loop goes *up to* the 5th index, meaning it iterates over exactly 5 elements.

This leads me into your next question:

> and in the place of what should be the 10th number is -858993460

You are getting this value because it is just a place holder in your array. This happened because you never got to assign the very last element from the user *BUT* when you print the results, notice how your `for...` loop prints out your array:

> for (y = 0; y < x; y++)

See how you're printing all the elements? But since you never assigned the last element from the user input, this causes undefined behavior in c++. In this case, it just print the memory address of where the last element is supposed to be in your array.

For a fun exercise, make an empty array and print it, you'll get the same result, with it printing random values (possibly memory addresses).

```cpp
int arry[10];
for(int i = 0, i < 10; i++)
{
   cout << arry[i] << " ";
}
```

Sorry for the long explanation but I hope this helps!! c:

Comment: some nitpicking: while reading a random value ("place holder" as you call it) is a possible result of the UB, that is just one of the endless possibilities (in practice only a few). The program can crash or manifest in any other way, including appear to manifest a bug in another seemingly unrelated piece of code. Also in this case it's not a memory address that is printed, it's the leftover value found at that address (the last element position). Again that is neither guaranteed, nor to be expected, UB means anything can happen.

Comment: @bolov OH! I never knew that! Thank you so much for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this `for (y = 0; y < (x - 1); y++)` twice when line I should have put `for(y=0; y<x; y++)`